# Call a base class' member function explicitly static

Tags: php, static, overloading

I have a base class with the magic methods `__call` and `_callStatic` defined, so that calls to undeclared member functions are handled.

When You have both, the non-static and static ones, it seems to not be possible to call the static one from a derived class, because the static operator `::` does not implicitly mean `static` if used with `parent` or, as in this case, the name of the base class. This is a special syntax explained here: http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php

What I want to do here is the derived class to call `__callStatic` which fails because the call defaults to being a non-static call and being handled by `__call`.

How can I make an explicitly static call on a base class' member function?

```
<?php

class MyBaseClass {

    public static function __callStatic($what, $args)
    {
        return 'static call';
    }
    
    public function __call($what, $args)
    {
        return 'non-static call';
    }

}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {

    function someAction()
    {
        //this seems to be interpreted as parent::Foo()
        //and so does not imply a static call
        return MyBaseClass::Foo(); //
    }

}

$bar = new MyDerivedClass();
echo $bar->someAction(); //outputs 'non-static call'

?>
```

Note that removing the non-static `__call` method makes the script output 'static call' because the `__callStatic` is called, when `__call` is not declared.

Comment: Uh oh... at first sight this looks like a bug.

Comment: I reported it and it was rated "not a bug" https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62393

Comment: Typical **useless** response from PHP core devs <sigh>. The answer you got is misleading *at best*, because you are not calling `parent::foo()` (which would be a non-static call indeed as the reply says).

Comment: I 'm guessing what happens is that on calling `->someAction()` there's a flag being set somewhere that says "the current call is being made in object context", and that trips up the binding resolver later.

Comment: For real fun, you can move the static call outside of the class hiearchy... So it's calling a static on an unrelated method. Guess what happens? `$this` will be defined, but `$this instanceof self` will return false. it's a WTF...

Comment: Can sb tell me why calling ::Foo() actually points to __call ? Is the `__call` function name reserved and automatically linked¿

Comment: @Sebas because http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid such behaviour you may use an empty proxy class, that is not linking `parent` and `MyBaseClass` during runtime:

```
class MyBaseClass {

    public static function __callStatic($what, $args)
    {
        return 'static call ' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __call($what, $args)
    {
        return 'dynamic call ' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class ProxyClass extends MyBaseClass {
    //"Empty" class
}

class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {

    function someAction()
    {
        return ProxyClass::Foo();
    }

}

$bar = new MyDerivedClass();
var_dump($bar->someAction()); //outputs 'static call'
```

http://pastebin.com/7JMJUmXt

Comment: I like Your workaround, because I don't have to change that much. Thank You!